# Git workflow explanation

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Below is screenshot of Git process from IntelliJ,

1. I am unable to understand what down arrow means?
2. why there are different colors? Do they refer to different branches?

[image]

I have understood every circle represents commit.

Comment: Those open arrows probably mean that there is a parent for that commit that is linked not directly **in the UI** (to avoid clutter, I would assume... other UIs do the same, like `gitk`).... so you click on the arrow and it will take you to the parent commit.

Comment: About colors, they have no meaning from git's POV... it's not related to branches or anything.... git history is just a graph of commits that point to their parents... it does _not_ keep track of _branches_ involved... all it cares about are commits (and branches are just pointers to commits that can be moved around at will).

Comment: You can’t visualize the usual graphs people make when they merge on every single update without these ellipsis arrows.